Shortcut for changing background color
I often highlight parts of my notebooks in different colours. I have always used the mouse to do this: Format--> Background Color--> Color. This gets tedious. Is there any way to assign a keyboard shortcut to a particular color?

Perhaps creating a pallete is more useful to you? Palette to highlight a part of an Input expression Or you can combine the answer there with the creation of a new keyboard shortcut (please search this site for instructions).

Is there any way to apply the palette to the background instead of the text itself? If not, I can try to work around the text colour but I'm kind of in the middle of a project that uses highlights and changing conventions isn't really practical now.

Oh, of course, sorry. Just replace FontColor with Background in my code :)
